# I've tried and tried, but the option to buy Pokecoins in the Pokemon Go shop still isn't there

Tags: pokemon-go

There is the option to buy all the usual items, such as Poke balls, incense, etc. But then I scroll down, see the area to insert promo codes, and beneath it? Nothing! During quarantine, I can't send my Pokemon to gyms because all of them are so far away from where I live, and when I turn on a VPN, the game is unplayable!

I've tried:

- killing and redownloading the game
- turning off parental controls
- giving the game unrestricted access
- I've toyed with the google play store's settings plenty, turning shit on and off and seeing if it works
- signing out and logging back in again.

Nothing is working.

Answer (score 3):

[Niantic has an article regarding not seeing PokeCoins for sale in the shop.](https://niantic.helpshift.com/a/pokemon-go/?s=shop&f=i-cannot-see-pokecoins-for-sale-in-the-shop&l=en&p=web) Their recommendations, which you should try first:

- Check that purchase restrictions are enabled
- Check that Pokemon Go is connected to your Google Play Services, including on background. Go to Settings > Data usage > Google Play Services, and check that  background data is enabled.
- Check you are connected to a reliable data connnection

Otherwise this could be a bug. Other options you can try to debug:

- Turning the phone on and off
- Remove and redownload the app
- Try to open a gift when your item storage is full. A pop-up message will appear which will give you the option of going to the shop to purchase more item bag space. Going to the shop menu in this fashion may potentially let you find the coin purchase option. Alternatives include trying to catch a Pokemon will full storage, or trying to enter a raid without a raid pass.
- Send Niantic an email describing your issue. You should include the version of your phone and Pokemon Go in your email.